# Ms access query generating field with custom data without tables

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

For example I want to generate field that contains 100 prime numbers.
Then, I want to use this query as a base for another query or report.

Comment: Contrary to the response you selected as the answer, this may not be impossible in Access. That will depend on where you want those numbers to come from. Are there a certain set of numbers you'd like to use? Are the numbers being generated according to some formula?

Comment: @KevenDenen. Yes, really I want to generate some date sequence. For example "Dec, 2013"; "Jan, 2014"; "Feb, 2014" restricted by some criteria (first month, current Month). Than I want to use it in crosstab query or in the report with one page for month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In access this is impossible. So you have to create table and put data there.

Comment: OK, it is a pity. Thank you

Comment: This is not impossible in access.

Comment: @KevenDenen is it possible to generate PRIME NUMBERS in one query?

Comment: @4dmonster, question was in generate some data in query without creation table. Of course, I'll generate data in function